# How can I replace substrings without delimiters(separadores) in docx file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docx

I am working on a Node.js project where I need to edit .docx files, specifically using the docxtemplater library. I have a structured .docx file that I cannot modify. How can I replace substrings without delimiters, such as "WHAT WE DISCUSS," using the docxtemplater library?

Here's a simplified representation of the document structure:

```
....
[DATE] | WHAT WE DISCUSS
Chairperson: [Name]
1.[TOPIC][Name]...
2.[TOPIC][Name]...
3.[TOPIC][Name]...
... [TOPIC] ... [Name] ...
Opening words (1 min.)
...
[DATE] | WHAT WE DISCUSS
Chairperson: [Name]
... [TOPIC] ... [Name] ...
... [TOPIC] ... [Name] ...
Opening words (1 min.) [Name]
...
```

Moreover, what is an efficient way to delete specific lines
"2.[TOPIC][Name]..." from the .docx file?

Also I want the next line to change from "3.[TOPIC][Name]..." to "2.[TOPIC][Name]..."

maybe use another library?